# AsyncCallback throws exception

Tags: winforms, exception, callback

In a Winform I get the exception: "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created" during an AsyncCallback.

The application works normally on other computers. I was wondering whether there might be a computer or network setting that could be responsible for the exception. The callback is a cross-domain callback, however all data are received and displayed in the Winform, then the exception occurs.

The exception is a fatal exception and the Windows message "App.. has stopped working" appears.

EDIT 1:

```
public void OpenFormCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // 'this' is a Winform  
    this.BeginInvoke(new DelegateVoid(SetDataSource));
}
```

Normally it works, now in the exceptional case there exists a very fast network connection which may be the cause for the fact that a handle is not yet created. Just realised that.

Should I try:

```
public void OpenFormCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // 'this' is a Winform  
        while (!this.IsHandleCreated) { }
        this.BeginInvoke(new DelegateVoid(SetDataSource));
    }
```

? Risking an eternal loop?

EDIT 2: I tried:

```
public void OpenFormCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // 'this' is a Winform  
        if (IsHandleCreated) { CreateHandle() }
        this.BeginInvoke(new DelegateVoid(SetDataSource));
    }
```

But the main form is not displayed, it comes in the state "Not responding".

Comment: Is there a place in your code where you call `Control.Invoke`? Or you are not sure where it gets called?

Answer (score 0):

Add checking `yourform.IsHandleCreated` before calling invoke/BeginInvoke from your callback

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void OpenFormCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    while (!this.IsHandleCreated) { Application.DoEvents(); }
    this.BeginInvoke(new DelegateVoid(SetDataSource));
}
```